# Make multiple csvs from an array of queried IDs

Tags: php, csv

### Trying to do

I'm trying to just write a php file that will be ran one time that generates a csv file for each client in its own folder with its respective name.

### What my code currently does

My code currently gets through about half of my clients company names and outputs a file called 'records.csv' in each of those folders, then I start getting the following two errors over and over again:

- Invalid argument supplied for foreach in *Directory* on line 32.
- `fputcsv()` expects parameters 2 to be array, string given in *Directory* on line 44.

The afforementioned files do get created yet nothing is being written correctly to them.

### Foreword to my code

I didn't like using a nested foreach here(just doesn't seem like a good practice to me), but this is only to be ran once but will still have to pull all current clients so the first statement sql statement is necessary.

```
<?php
//make connection
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

//check connection
if ($connection->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

//get IDs for clients
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'clients' GROUP BY post_title";
$IDs = array();
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("initial query wasn't found");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$IDs[] = $row["ID"];
}
//query using ID to match parent data
foreach ($IDs as $ID) {
$company_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE post_parent = ".$ID."";
$name_result = mysqli_query($connection, $company_query) or die("this query failed");
$companies = array();
$companies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_result);

 foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $folder_raw = $companies["post_title"];
    $folder_clean = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $folder_raw);
    //make directory
    $folder_name = './' . $folder_clean . '/';
    if(!mkdir($folder_name, 0777, true)){
        die("failed to make folder");
    }

    //make and open file
    $file_name = $folder_name . 'records' . ".csv";
    $fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $company);
    //close file
    fclose($fp);
    break;
  }
 }
}
?>
```

### Suggested Change

```
foreach ($IDs as $ID) {
$company_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE post_parent = ".$ID."";
$name_result = mysqli_query($connection, $company_query) or die("this query failed");
$companies = array();
$companies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_result))
 {

    $folder_raw = $row["post_title"];
    $folder_clean = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $folder_raw);
    $folder_name = './' . $folder_clean . '/';
    if(!mkdir($folder_name, 0777, true)){
        die("failed to make folder");
    }
    $file_name = $folder_name . 'records' . ".csv";
    $fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $company);
    fclose($fp);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem stems from the use of [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).  This fetches 1 row as an associative array, and it looks like you are treating the result as an array of arrays in the foreach.  This might be working because you don't ever use `$company` itself, but access members of `$companies` within the loop.

I would change

```
$companies = array();
$companies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_result);

foreach ($companies as $company) {
  $folder_raw = $companies["post_title"];
```

to

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_result))
{
  $folder_raw = $row["post_title"];
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I changed that last foreach to a that while and tested it out. That only created one folder of the first client and a blank csv. I'm not too concerned about the blank csv as I am creating all the folders.

Comment: Can you post your change?

Comment: My change is now above in the suggested change section

Comment: Thanks, you need to remove the two lines above the while loop entirely.  Look at my suggested changes, how I removed `$companies` altogether.

Comment: I was able to get through the queries again. I'm thinking some of the missing folders are because they aren't getting pulled in from the query. I'm going to dig through that in a `var_dump` if that's the case I will mark this as answered, thanks